# Issue with arorner when doing validation on a TextBox control

Tags: wpf, validation, textbox, adorner

[image]

I am validating a `TextBox` control for a particular range. If user enter a value out of range, an `Adorner` control as shown in the image above is shown.

My problem is the control is cut beyond the window size. How do I place the red adorner above the window even though the window size is smaller as above.

Below is the code I have used for a `ControlTemplate` and `Style`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <TextBlock Name="ErrorText" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Foreground="White"  
                                   FontSize="12" Padding="7" FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" 
                                   Margin="5,5,0,0"                                        
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"                                        
                                   Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" >             
                <TextBlock.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.95"></SolidColorBrush>
                </TextBlock.Background>
            </TextBlock>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="ErrorTextBox" />
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="ValidationStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect Color="Red" ShadowDepth="5" Direction="135" Opacity="0.5"></DropShadowEffect>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not aware that `Adorner`s can be rendered outside of the window, so for your question, you can't place `Adorner` outside of window.

However, popup is usually used, when you need behaviour like that. Just wrap everything into `Popup` element, and see if it helps.